# Handling response timeout in android using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to catch basically two types of errors in android using volley. I have used errorListener for failed api calls. Below is what I am doing.

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            if(error instanceof NoConnectionError)
            {
                // Did not connect
            }
            else if(error instanceof TimeoutError)
            {
             //Response Timeout error is what I have assumed.
            }

        }
    };
```

I am basically interested to distinguish between ConnectionTimeOut and ResponseTimeOut. Is this correct

Edit:
I need to make an API call for some validation and I am on 2G. The request is sent to the server but response is not received due to timeout. So I want to know if the request was delivered to server or the request was not at all sent to the server. From what I assume is if the client didn't connect to server it will be connectiontimeout error, else if the request is sent to the server and response is not obtained by the client then it would be timeout. So is my understanding is right or I am missing something?

Comment: what is your question actually? what to do when you get the specific errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use HTTP codes for this.

If its a 408 error, its a Request Timeout

> The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time.

And if its a 504

> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI (e.g. HTTP, FTP, LDAP) or some other auxiliary server (e.g. DNS) it needed to access in attempting to complete the request.

And for getting the error code you do:

```
error.networkResponse.statusCode
```

[Source](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)